# Scala: Partitioning by case (not by filter)

Tags: scala

I have a list of mixed values:

```
val list = List("A", 2, 'c', 4)
```

I know how to collect the chars, or strings, or ints, in a single operation:

```
val strings = list collect { case s:String => s }
==> List(A)
val chars = list collect { case c:Char => c }
==> List(c)
val ints = list collect { case i:Int => i }
==> List(2,4)
```

Can I do it all in one shot somehow? I'm looking for:

```
val (strings, chars, ints) = list ??? {
  case s:String => s
  case c:Char => c
  case i:Int => i
}
```

**EDIT**
Confession -- An example closer to my actual use case:

I have a list of things, that I want to partition according to some conditions:

```
val list2 = List("Word", "   ", "", "OtherWord")
val (empties, whitespacesonly, words) = list2 ??? {
  case s:String if s.isEmpty => s
  case s:String if s.trim.isEmpty => s
  case s:String => s
}
```

N.B. `partition` would be great for this if I only had 2 cases (one where the condition was met and one where it wasn't) but here I have multiple conditions to split on.

Comment: How did you end up with that list in the first place?

Comment: @Reactormonk: See my second example.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your second example: you can use `groupBy` and a key-ing function.  I prefer to use those techniques in conjunction with a  [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) to make the intention of the code more obvious:

```
val list2 = List("Word", "   ", "", "OtherWord")

sealed trait Description
object Empty extends Description
object Whitespaces extends Description
object Words extends Description

def strToDesc(str : String) : Description = str match {
  case _ if str.isEmpty()        => Empty
  case _ if str.trim.isEmpty()   => Whitespaces
  case _                         => Words
}

val descMap = (list2 groupBy strToDesc) withDefaultValue List.empty[String]

val (empties, whitespaceonly, words) =
  (descMap(Empty),descMap(Whitespaces),descMap(Words))
```

This extends well if you want to add another Description later, e.g. `AllCaps`...

Comment: Interesting approach: Introduce symbols to act as the result of my match, group on it, and later extract the values of the resulting map

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help:

```
list.foldLeft((List[String](), List[String](), List[String]())) {
  case ((e,s,w),str:String) if str.isEmpty => (str::e,s,w)
  case ((e,s,w),str:String) if str.trim.isEmpty => (e,str::s,w)
  case ((e,s,w),str:String) => (e,s,str::w)
  case (acc, _) => acc
}
```

Comment: This is really nice: putting guards in front of the case statements in the foldLeft function itself. Two questions. 1: What is the purpose of the final case? Just sort of a catch-all in case the other cases don't match? 2: Do the results need to be reversed, as in @PeterNeyens' example?

Comment: 1. The final case is for non-String entries, like in your first example - I was not sure if list can contain only String or not
2. If the order of entries is important - yes, results should be reversed, or whole solution should be remastered using foldRight

Answer (score 2):

You could use `partition` twice :

```
def partitionWords(list: List[String]) = {
  val (emptyOrSpaces, words) = list.partition(_.trim.isEmpty)
  val (empty, spaces) = emptyOrSpaces.partition(_.isEmpty)
  (empty, spaces, words)
}
```

Which gives for your example :

```
partitionWords(list2)
// (List(""),List("   "),List(Word, OtherWord))
```

In general you can use `foldLeft` with a tuple as accumulator.

```
def partitionWords2(list: List[String]) = {
  val nilString = List.empty[String]
  val (empty, spaces, words) = list.foldLeft((nilString, nilString, nilString)) { 
    case ((empty, spaces, words), elem) => 
      elem match {
        case s if s.isEmpty      => (s :: empty, spaces, words)
        case s if s.trim.isEmpty => (empty, s :: spaces, words)
        case s                   => (empty, spaces, s :: words)
      }
  }
  (empty.reverse, spaces.reverse, words.reverse)
}
```

Which will give you the same result.

Comment: Also interesting! My initial reaction to this is that this is closer to my desired result, but I don't know enough about Scala and the runtime to comment on the performance characteristics: specifically there are a lot of temporary tuples being set up and torn down (one per source element). Can you comment?

Answer (score 1):

A tail recursive method,

```
def partition(list: List[Any]): (List[Any], List[Any], List[Any]) = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def inner(map: Map[String, List[Any]], innerList: List[Any]): Map[String, List[Any]] = innerList match {
      case x :: xs => x match {
        case s: String => inner(insertValue(map, "str", s), xs)
        case c: Char   => inner(insertValue(map, "char", c), xs)
        case i: Int    => inner(insertValue(map, "int", i), xs)
      }
      case Nil => map
    }

    def insertValue(map: Map[String, List[Any]], key: String, value: Any) = {
      map + (key -> (value :: map.getOrElse(key, Nil)))
    }

    val partitioned = inner(Map.empty[String, List[Any]], list)
    (partitioned.get("str").getOrElse(Nil), partitioned.get("char").getOrElse(Nil), partitioned.get("int").getOrElse(Nil))
  }

  val list1 = List("A", 2, 'c', 4)

  val (strs, chars, ints) = partition(list1)
```

Comment: Your `insertValue` could be implemented simpler : `map + (key -> (value :: map.getOrElse(key, Nil)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up with this, based on @Nyavro's answer:

```
val list2 = List("Word", "   ", "", "OtherWord")
val(empties, spaces, words) = 
  list2.foldRight((List[String](), List[String](), List[String]())) {
    case (str, (e, s, w)) if str.isEmpty =>      (str :: e, s, w)
    case (str, (e, s, w)) if str.trim.isEmpty => (e, str :: s, w)
    case (str, (e, s, w)) =>                     (e, s, str :: w)
  }
==> empties: List[String] = List("")
==> spaces: List[String] = List("   ")
==> words: List[String] = List(Word, OtherWord)
```

I understand the risks of using `foldRight`: mainly that in order to start on the right, the runtime needs to recurse and that this may blow the stack on large inputs. However, my inputs are small and this risk is acceptable.

Having said that, if there's a quick way to `_.reverse` three lists of a tuple that I haven't thought of, I'm all ears.

Thanks all!

Comment: You don't need to worry about the stack. From the Scala library source: `override def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
    reverse.foldLeft(z)((right, left) => op(left, right))
`